# AngularJS: How to filter Object Array Except one property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Angular $filter can do string fuzzy search for Object Array,

But every of My Objects have one property of base64 pic.

```
var MyObjects = [{
    property1: 'ab',
    property2: 'cd',
    pic: '4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBw.....' 
}, {
    property1: 'ef',
    property2: 'gh',
    pic: '4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBw.....' 
}, {
    ....


}],

result = $filter('filter')(MyObjects, $scope.searchText);
```

How can I except pic property in fuzzy search?

Answer (score 1):

Angular's filter can take a function as an argument to filter your array. The filter will select items that the function returns true for.

You can use this feature to achieve what you want.

[Here is the official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

So, you could do something like this to compare the search text only with the two properties you want to:

```
var filterFunction = function(item) {
    var val = $scope.searchText
    return item.property1.indexOf(val || '') !== -1 || item.property2.indexOf(val || '') !== -1;
}

result = $filter('filter')(MyObjects, filterFunction, $scope.searchText);
```

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating this effect.](http://jsfiddle.net/EqsyT/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I ended up implementing it. Angular custom filters seem to be the way to go for this sort of problem. [You can find more about them from Angular](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/filter/filter), but in this implementation you can add any other fields you'd like to leave off by adding another `&& key != "unwantedKey"`.  The value of the key must be a string for the indexOf to work so the `typeof` portion makes sure we don't get any ids that are numbers, etc.

```
$scope.search = function(item){ 
    for (var key in item){
        if (typeof key === "string" && key != "pic"){ 

            if(item[key].indexOf($scope.query) > -1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```